# Show Image in Gallery

Tags: java, android, imageview

my Activity has several`ImageView` items. Additionally I want that the user can click on an image and the gallery app opens it.

Is this possible?

I have a `CursorAdapter` and I'm using this to set the image.

```
try {
ConversationImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
    }
});

ConversationImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(Content));
ConversationImage.setClickable(true);

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "ConversationImage");
    Log.d(TAG, textContent);
}
```

So I have the URI in the String "Content".

Thanks

P.S.
I think that my idea to open the gallery is not the right way. I will write a own activity to display images.

Comment: try this Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
Main.this.startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was searching for was this:

```
.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent photoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                        File file = new File(imageString);
                        photoIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),
                                "image/*");

                        context.startActivity(photoIntent);

                    }
                });
```

I understood how to use it while I was reading this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 1):

My solution :

1) Creating variable PICK_FROM_FILE:

```
private static final int PICK_FROM_FILE = 1;
```

2) Start ACTION_PICK

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICK_FROM_FILE);
```

3) Image Recovery

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_FROM_FILE:
            Uri photoUri  = intent.getData();
            if (photoUri != null) {
                //YOUR TREATMENT
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this option too:

```
private static final int gallerycode = 1;

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
i.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "select pic"), gallerycode);
```